# Python OpenCV: Sorting Points based on Nearest Neighbor

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently working on an OpenCV project right now.

So basically, I need to find the length between the red lines. The photo on the right is a product of the Zhang-Suen skeletoning technique.

In OpenCV, points are sorted based on the column and then rows. How can I sort the array such that it is sorted in a way that it forms a continuous line?

I already have two arrays, one from the x-coordinates and one from the y-coordinates. Each indexes indicated an existing point between the red lines.

[image]

This is how OpenCV automatically stored its points

[image]

Comment: You can create a graph representation from a skeleton with [skan package](https://skeleton-analysis.org/stable/index.html). See the API reference of [Skeleton class](https://skeleton-analysis.org/stable/api/skan.csr.html). If you have specific issues, please share your code so far!

Comment: Finding nearest distance of successive points might be a good start

Comment: BFS. Definitely BFS.

Comment: @Melon were you able to solve this?

Comment: @JeruLuke yes, I did. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X and Y coordinates must be combined and stored in an array.
Then, you sort it according to an ascending order of X-coordinates.
From there, it will start at the very left corner. Then you apply the sorting algorithm.

Note: This algorithm won't work on noisy datasets. Only on continuous ones.
Supposed x is the array of your x coordinates and y is the array or y coordinates

```
for x in range(len(x):
    dataset.append([x[x],y[x]])

dataset.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
dataset = np.array(dataset)
dataset = sorted(dataset, key = lambda point: self.euclidian_distance(point,dataset[0]))

def euclidian_distance(self, a,b):
    return np.linalg.norm(a-b)
```